# MySQL - Update Parent Table Based on Concatenated JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update, concatenation

I have a table of legacy makes/models that are concatenated together, but I've built two new tables with the distinct makes and models that I would like to use to update the table of legacy makes/models to allow for easier updates. The tables look like this:

```
===============================================   
| tb_legacy                                   |   
===============================================   
| f_makemodel          | f_makeID | f_modelID | 
|----------------------|----------|-----------|   
| CHEVROLET CAPRICE    |   NULL   |   NULL    |
| CHEVROLET 1500 TRUCK |   NULL   |   NULL    |   
| FORD MUSTANG         |   NULL   |   NULL    | 
-----------------------------------------------

=============================    =============================
| tb_makes                  |    | tb_models                 |
=============================    =============================
| f_makeID | f_makename     |    | f_modelID | f_modelname   |
-----------------------------    -----------------------------
|    1     | Chevrolet      |    |     1     | Caprice       |
|    2     | Ford           |    |     2     | 1500 Truck    |
-----------------------------    |     3     | Mustang       |
                                 -----------------------------
```

What I want to do is **`UPDATE`** the `tb_legacy` table with the `f_makeID` and `f_modelID` fields so that I end up with the `tb_legacy` field looking like this:

```
===============================================   
| tb_legacy                                   |   
===============================================   
| f_makemodel          | f_makeID | f_modelID | 
|----------------------|----------|-----------|   
| CHEVROLET CAPRICE    |    1     |     1     |
| CHEVROLET 1500 TRUCK |    1     |     2     |   
| FORD MUSTANG         |    2     |     3     | 
-----------------------------------------------
```

I have a SQL Fiddle showing the **`SELECT`** query:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pSJiMHNJPB6pBLfYTMCHgX/6

How can create an **`UPDATE`** query to accomplish the desired result?

### EDIT:

The following illustrates what I want to do, but

```sql
UPDATE tb_legacy
SET tb_legacy.f_makeID = 
(
    SELECT tb_makes.f_makeID
    FROM tb_legacy, tb_makes, tb_models
    WHERE tb_legacy.f_makemodel = CONCAT(tb_makes.f_makename,' ',tb_models.f_modelname)
),
tb_legacy.f_modelID = 
(
    SELECT tb_models.f_modelID
    FROM tb_legacy, tb_makes, tb_models
    WHERE tb_legacy.f_makemodel = CONCAT(tb_makes.f_makename,' ',tb_models.f_modelname)
)
```

But the above query returns the following error:
***`Error: ER_UPDATE_TABLE_USED: You can't specify target table 'tb_legacy' for update in FROM clause`***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join `tb_legacy` to the other 2 tables like this:

```
UPDATE tb_legacy lg
INNER JOIN tb_makes mk ON lg.f_makemodel LIKE CONCAT(mk.f_makename, ' ', '%')
INNER JOIN tb_models md ON lg.f_makemodel LIKE CONCAT('%', ' ', md.f_modelname)
SET lg.f_makeID = mk.f_makeID,
    lg.f_modelID = md.f_modelID
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=30ce4181dea4b8b56e472fe419eb8304).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
 update tb_legacy 
 set f_makeID=t.f_makeID, f_modelID=l.f_modelID
 from tb_makes t
 join tb_legacy l
 ON tb_legacy.f_makemodel = CONCAT(t.f_makename,' ',l.f_modelname)
```

Comment: I think that's close, but we need to CONCAT the tb_makes and tb_models rather than the tb_makes with the tb_legacy, and need to also JOIN the tb_models table.

Comment: @Beems what do you mean by *that's close*. This does not even run because it is not MySql syntax.

Comment: @forpas I was trying to be nice, because it gave me some avenues to research further. And no, it wasn't me that upvoted that answer.